# GetPrivateProfileStringA is returning "The system cannot find the file specified." eventhough the file exists

Tags: c++, ini

in CPP Visual studio 2010. I need to read some configurations from ini file. the below code is not working. can someone help me fix it.

```
char * path  = "C:\\NotBackedUp\\Workspaces\\LDAP-DLL\\LDAPTestApp\\bin\\Debug\\conf\\ldap.ini";
    std::wcout << "path: " << path << std::endl;

    if(!ATLPath::FileExists(path))
    {
        HRESULT hr = ATL::AtlHresultFromLastError();
        ATLTRACE("%x\n",hr);//system could not find the file specified!
        std::cout << "File not found " << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else 
    {
        std::cout << "File found " << std::endl;
    }

    char valueRead[320];
    int a = GetPrivateProfileStringA("ldap", "url", "error", valueRead, 320, path);
    std::cout << "Value Read " << valueRead << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Error String " << GetLastErrorAsString();
```

the above code is generating below log, you can see ATLPath::FileExists is returning true, but still getLastError is stating the System cannot find the file specified

```
path: C:\NotBackedUp\Workspaces\LDAP-DLL\LDAPTestApp\bin\Debug\conf\ldap.ini
File found
Value Read error
Error String The system cannot find the file specified.
```

My ldap.ini file has following lines and is available in the above path

```
[ldap]
url=ldap://testserver
```

any help is highly appreciated

thanks

Comment: [`GetPrivateProfileString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724353(v=vs.85).aspx) is for 16bit compatibility only and should be avoided, if you need all user shared config consider using either the registry or a configuration file.

Comment: As said in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724353(v=vs.85).aspx): `Note  This function is provided only for compatibility with 16-bit Windows-based applications. Applications should store initialization information in the registry.`. Maybe you should store your information not in an ini file but in the registry. Or write your own ini file parser because this WinAPI function is deprecated.

Comment: The function succeeded (in the sense that it returned a valid string). Calling `GetLastError` after success will return garbage. Even if it had failed, you are calling `GetLastError` far too late. You do a bunch of other things in between calling `GetPrivateProfileStringA` and calling `GetLastError`, any of which could have reset `GetLastError`.

Comment: You make an effort to use a full path name.  But then you don't use it and only pass "ldap" to the function.  Instead of `path`.  The odds that the current working directory is set correctly is always low, zero when you ask a question like this one.  Use `path`.

Comment: @Andre Kampling, if it was only for a backward compatibility, then why did they enhance the api to support unicode characters. In WinBase.h you see this line 

#ifdef UNICODE
#define GetPrivateProfileString  GetPrivateProfileStringW
#else
#define GetPrivateProfileString  GetPrivateProfileStringA
#endif // !UNICODE

Answer (score 0):

The ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND error code you’re getting is also set when GetPrivateProfileString is unable to find a section or value.

Your code works fine on my Win10 with your ini file.

Use a hex viewer/editor to verify your ldap.ini is actually ASCII, and that it doesn't contain [BOM](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html).